# Defining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers

Tags: macros, numbering

I tend to use `\newcommand` to define macros for symbols I use often, e.g. `\newcommand{\hankel}{H^{(1)}_0}`.  One inconvenience of this approach is the fact that command names cannot include numbers.  What I ideally want is to map something like `\H0` to `H^{(1)}_0`.  I imagine this could be done with some macro expansion/snippet package, or one might use `\newcommand` to define a command that takes a parameter, etc.  Before I start experimenting, though -- is there a canonical way of dealing with this problem?

Comment: I think it is important to know what other commands `\H...` you're going to need. Is it as in Jan's answer? Then that one's perfect for you. If not, can you add some explanation to your question?

Comment: Jan's answer works well for many of my use cases; it looks to me like other solutions are cumbersome or have side effects.  I often use variables/identifiers with numbers when I compute things, and it is annoying that I cannot reuse these names in LaTeX -- that was my main motivation for asking the question.  For the time being I think I'll stick with either not using numbers, or using command parameters as per Jan's suggestion.

Comment: It would be really interesting for me to see other command with numbers that you'd like to use.

Comment: @Hendrik: how about H2O? :)  (I am not a chemist, so I actually don't care much about that one.)  In truth, almost all my use cases involve subscripts and superscripts -- perhaps used as powers or to indicate matrix elements.  So `\newcommand` parameters will work well.

Comment: That's a good one, thanks. One _could_ handle such cases, but it wouldn't be nice. Good that you mostly want sub- und superscripts only!

Comment: Related Question: [newcommand name cannot include numbers for example \Mycomand123](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66666/newcommand-name-cannot-include-numbers-for-example-mycomand123) which actually references a package that allows one to do this.

Comment: ^^ (.note for future readers) That linked question also explain what is going on internally.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Defining commands with parameters would be the way I would deal with this.

```
\newcommand{\H}[1]{H^{(1)}_{#1}}
```

defines a command with one parameter.  You can then do `\H0`, `\H1`, ..., `\H9`. 
For more than one digit, you will have to use it as `\H{10}`.

Comment: Although this does address the particular example, a problem is that you may want the parameter to be omitted when it has a particular value, e.g. you want to write H2O but if 2 is 1 instead you want to write HO not H1O. Is there a way to achieve that with this approach? Sorry if this should be  a different question.

Comment: yes, you can check for special case with \if ... commands in the macro definition

Comment: It seems you never cite Pàl Erd\H{o}s in your papers. If you had Erdös number 2 as I have (B-)), you'd probably elaborate a little on that point. (Hint: use e.g. \ifmmode {your definition} \else \HH and first "backup" \let\HH=\H

Answer (score 70):

[This faq answer](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-linmacnames) discusses this issue, criticises 4 possible ways of using such a macro and ultimately comes to the conclusion *don't do that*.

> New LaTeX users are often suprised that macro definitions
> containing non-letters, such as
>
> ```latex
> \newcommand{\cul8r}{Goodbye!}
> ```
>
> fail to compile.  The reason is that the TeX macro language, unlike
> most programming languages, allows
> nothing but letters in macro names.
>
> There are a number of techniques for defining a macro with a name like
> `\cul8r`.  Unfortunately, none of the techniques is particularly
> good:
>
> 1. Use `\csname`…`\endcsname` to define and invoke the
>    macro:
>
>    ```latex
>    \expandafter\newcommand\csname cul8r\endcsname{Goodbye!}
>    I said, ``\csname cul8r\endcsname''.
>    ```
>
>    - Pro: No unexpected side effects
>    - Con: So verbose as to be unusable
> 2. Define a "special-command generator", and  use the resulting
>    commands:
>
>    ```latex
>    \newcommand{\DefineRemark}[2]{%
>      \expandafter\newcommand\csname rmk-#1\endcsname{#2}%
>    }
>    \newcommand{\Remark}[1]{\csname rmk-#1\endcsname}
>    ...
>    \DefineRemark{cul8r}{Goodbye!}
>    ...
>    \Remark{cul8r}
>    ```
>
>    - Pro: Straightforward to use, not too untidy
>    - Con: It's hardly doing what we set out to do (experts will
>      see that you are defining a macro, but others likely won't)
> 3. Convince TeX that `8` is a letter:
>
>    ```latex
>    \catcode`8 = 11 
>    \newcommand{\cul8r}{Goodbye!}
>    I said, ``\cul8r''.
>    ```
>
>    - Pro: `\cul8r` can be used directly
>    - Con: Likely to break other uses of `8` (such as
>      numbers or dimensions; so
>      `\setlength{`\paperwidth`}{8in}` tells us:
>
>    ```latex
>    ! Missing number, treated as zero.
>    <to be read again> 
>                       8
>    ```
>
>    As a general rule, changing category codes is something to use
>    *in extremis*, after detailed examination of options.  It is
>    conceivable that such drastic action could be useful for you, but
>    most ordinary users are well advised not even to try such a
>    technique.
> 4. Define a macro `\cul` which must always be followed by
>    `8r`:
>
>    ```latex
>    \def\cul8r{Goodbye!}
>    I said, ``\cul8r''.
>    ```
>
>    - Pro: `\cul8r` can be used directly
>    - Con #1: Breaks if `\cul` is followed by anything other
>      than `8r`, with a confusing diagnostic —
>      `\cul99` produces:
>
>    ```latex
>    ! Use of \cul doesn't match its definition.
>    <*> \cul9
>             9
>    ```
>
>    (which would confuse someone who hadn't even realised there
>    *was* a definition of `\cul` in the document).
>
>    - Con #2: Silently redefines existing `\cul`, if any;
>      as a result, the technique cannot be used to define both a
>      `\cul8r` and, say, a `\cul123` macro in the same
>      document.
>
> Technique 3 is in fact commonly used — in a limited form — within
> most LaTeX packages and within LaTeX itself.  The convention is to
> use `@` within the names of internal macros to hide them
> from the user and thereby prevent naming conflicts.  To this end,
> LaTeX automatically treats `@` as a letter while
> processing classes and packages and as a non-letter while processing
> the user's document.  The key to this technique is the separation:
> internally a non-letter is used for macro names, and the user doesn't
> see anything of it, while the status remains "frozen" in all the
> definitions created within the class or package.  See
> `\@` and `@` in macro names for
> more information.
>
> Note that analogous use of technique 3 in this example would give us
>
> ```latex
> \begingroup
>   \catcode`8 = 11 
>   \gdef\cul8r{Goodbye!}
>   \gdef\later{\cul8r}
> \endgroup
> I said, ``\later''.
> ```
>
> which works, but rather defeats the object of the exercise.
> (`\later` has the "frozen" catcode for "8", even though the value
> has reverted to normal by the time it's used; note, also, the use of
> the primitive command `\gdef`, since `\newcommand` can't make a
> macro that's available outside the group.)
>
> *Recommendation*: Either choose another mechanism (such as
> `\DefineRemark` above), or choose another name for your macro, one
> that contains only ordinary letters.  A common approach is to use
> roman numerals in place of arabic ones:
>
> ```latex
> \newcommand{\culVIIIr}{Goodbye!}
> ```
>
> which rather spoils the intent of the joke implicit in the example
> `\cul8r`!

Comment: if you only want to use \cul8r and no other \cul then you can also just gobble the next two items: \def\cul#1#2{Goodbye!} . It will always work, and \cul11 will give the same result. Furthermore you could use \if's in the definition to yield different results depending on the two tokens #1 and #2 that follow the \cul command.

Answer (score 20):

In some cases, using Roman rather than Arabic numerals may help: \HI, \HII, \HIII, \HIV.
This is also mentioned in Lev Bishop's link and helped in my case.

Comment: Though \HIV might be a little ambigious.

Comment: *Roman numerals?!* There's a reason we don't generally do arithmetic with Roman numerals.

Answer (score 8):

A bad hack (Jan's answer above is much better)  `:-)`:

```
\newcommand{\HH}{\afterassignment\HH@aux\count0=}
\newcommand{\HH@aux}{H^{(1)}_{\the\count0}}
```

between the usual `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`. If you want to define the commands for various numbers separately, you can do

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\GG}{\afterassignment\GG@aux\count0=}
\newcommand{\GG@aux}{\csname GG\the\count0\endcsname}
\makeatother
```

and define the various `\GG0`, `\GG1`... as

```
\expandafter\newcommand\csname GG0\endcsname{%
  Definition of GG0.}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname GG1\endcsname{%
  Definition of GG1.}

\GG0 \GG1 \GG2 ...
```

Note that when we call `\GG` followed by `2`, we don't get any error/warning: it is just ignored. This method could seem good, but it has many drawbacks, failing in unexpected cases. For instance, if `\foo` is say, `123`, then

```
\GG1\foo...
```

will be seen as `\GG1123`, not the expected behaviour.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `\usepackage{numdef}`:

http://web.archive.org/web/20130727172127/http://www.elec.ryukoku.ac.jp/~fujii/pub/ftp/incoming/styles/kth.se/numdef.sty

You can define `\num\def\x1{x one}` and use it as `\x1`.

Hope this helps! 
VIKI

Comment: I get ! `LaTeX Error: File ``numdef.sty'' not found.`

Comment: @Viesturs you've got to create a numdef.sty file that contains the code in the link provided.

Comment: Other link & more information: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66666/command-macro-name-cannot-include-numbers-and-symbols#comment818901_66695

Comment: This package does pretty-much the same thing as [Bruno's answer above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9728/250119) (i.e. grab the next number into a counter and call auxiliary function), but maybe more convenient as a premade package.

Answer (score 3):

If the command is guaranteed to be followed by *exactly one digit*, [`suffix` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/suffix) can be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{suffix}
\begin{document}

\WithSuffix\def\aa1#1{first (#1)}
\WithSuffix\def\aa2#1{second (#1)}
\aa1{123}
\aa2{456}

\end{document}
```

*maybe someone will write a `triedef` for the "general" case some time...*

Answer (score 1):

As under normal category code régime you cannot obtain control-word-tokens like `\H0` directly by having TeX read and tokenize .tex-input and as correct invocation of `\csname..\endcsname` in combination with `\expandafter` sometimes seems cumbersome, I offer a macro `\CsNameToCsToken` to create, e.g.,  the control-word-token `\H0` from the character-token-sequence `H0`.

Syntax:

`\CsNameToCsToken⟨stuff not in braces⟩{⟨NameOfCs⟩}`
→
`⟨stuff not in braces⟩\NameOfCs`

(`⟨stuff not in braces⟩` may be empty.)

(Due to `\romannumeral`-expansion the result is obtained by triggering two expansion-steps, e.g., by having two "hits" with `\expandafter`.)

With such a macro you are not bound to specific definition commands:

`\CsNameToCsToken{foo}` → `\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand{foo}` → `\newcommand\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\DeclareRobustCommand{foo}` → `\DeclareRobustCommand\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\global\long\outer\def{foo}` → `\global\long\outer\def\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter{foo}\bar` → `\expandafter\foo\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\let{foo}=\bar` → `\let\foo=\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\let{foo}={bar}` → `\CsNameToCsToken\let\foo={bar}` → `\let\foo=\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\string{foo}` → `\string\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\meaning{foo}` → `\meaning\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\NewDocumentCommand{foo}...` → `\NewDocumentCommand\foo...`  .

```latex
\makeatletter
%%===============================================================================
%% End \romannumeral-driven expansion safely:
%%===============================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%===============================================================================
%% Obtain control sequence token from name of control sequence token:
%%===============================================================================
%% \CsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs}
%% ->  <stuff not in braces>\NameOfCs
%% (<stuff not in braces> may be empty.)
\@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{%
  \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
Define \H0:
\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{H0}{H^{(1)}_0}
\end{verbatim}

\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{H0}{H^{(1)}_0}


\begin{verbatim}
Using \H0: 
\[\CsNameToCsToken{H0}\]
\end{verbatim}

\[\CsNameToCsToken{H0}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If the [most recent development release of LaTeX 2ε, 2022-06-01 Patch level -3,](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex-dev/) is in use, where `\ExpandArgs` as a wrapper for calling `\exp_args:N...`, and `\UseName` are available, you can do:

```latex
% \ExplSyntaxOn
% \cs_new_eq:NN \UseName \use:c
% \cs_new:Npn \ExpandArgs #1 {
%   \cs_if_exist_use:cF { exp_args:N #1 }
%   { \msg_expandable_error:nnn { kernel } { unknown-arg-expansion } {#1} }
% }
% \msg_new:nnn { kernel } { unknown-arg-expansion } { Unknown~arg~expansion~"#1" }
% \ExplSyntaxOff

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
Define \H0:
\ExpandArgs{Nc}\newcommand*{H0}{H^{(1)}_0}
\end{verbatim}

\ExpandArgs{Nc}\newcommand*{H0}{H^{(1)}_0}


\begin{verbatim}
Using \H0: 
\[\UseName{H0}\]
\end{verbatim}

\[\UseName{H0}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

In your question you use the command `\H`.

As that is already defined in LaTeX 2ε in the following part of this answer the command `\h` is used instead.

If you don't need the commands that are trailed by digits to be fully expandable, you can enhance one of the above examples with a mechanism

```
\DefineCatTwelveDigitsCall{⟨CsName⟩}
```

which defines `\CsName` to gather explicit catcode-12-digits from the token-stream and then to do `\csname CsName⟨gathered digits⟩\endcsname` if `\CsName⟨gathered digits⟩` is defined.

Be aware that at the time of tokenizing things the digits to be gathered are not part of the name of a control sequence token but are tokenized as explicit character tokens on their own; thus spaces following them are not discarded—with `\hello`  space-characters following the characters that form the single control-word-token `\hello` are discarded as TeX's reading apparatus switches to state S(skipping blanks) after tokenizing a control-word-token. With `\h10`  tokenizing yields the tokens: `\h`, `1`, `0` followed by a space token: After tokenizing the explicit character token `0` TeX's reading-apparatus is in state M(middle of line) and thus the subsequent space character in the TeX-input is not discarded/skipped but yields insertion of an explicit space-token into the token stream.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%
% \CheckWhetherExplicitCatTwelveDigit{<Tokens in case subsequent token is explicit catcode-12-digit>}%
%                                    {<Tokens in case subsequent token is not explicit catcode-12-digit>}%
%                                    <subsequent token>
%
%
% Unexpandable check whether subsequent token is explicit catcode-12-digit 
% Via \futurelet and \if the character-code of the next token is checked.
% If the subsequent token's corresponds to the character-code of a digit-token,
% it can safely be grabbed as macro-argument for forking via delimited arguments
% if it is really an explicit catcode-12-digit-character-token.
%
\newcommand\CheckWhetherExplicitCatTwelveDigit[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\@tempb{\unexpanded{#1}}%
  \edef\@tempc{\unexpanded{#2}}%
  \futurelet\@tempa\CheckWhetherDigitMeaning
}%
\newcommand\CheckWhetherDigitMeaning{%
  \if1\noexpand\@tempa\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
  {\if2\noexpand\@tempa\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
    {\if3\noexpand\@tempa\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
      {\if4\noexpand\@tempa\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
        {\if5\noexpand\@tempa\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
          {\if6\noexpand\@tempa\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
            {\if7\noexpand\@tempa\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
              {\if8\noexpand\@tempa\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
                {\if9\noexpand\@tempa\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
                  {\if0\noexpand\@tempa\expandafter\@secondoftwo\else\expandafter\@firstoftwo\fi
                     {\expandafter\endgroup\@tempc}%
                  }%
                }%
              }%
            }%
          }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  {\CheckWhetherExplicitDigit}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\ForkExplicitDigit{\long\def\ForkExplicitDigit#11234567890#2#3\relax{#2}}%
\newcommand\CheckWhetherExplicitDigit[1]{%
  \ForkExplicitDigit
  #1234567890{\expandafter\endgroup\@tempb}%
  1#134567890{\expandafter\endgroup\@tempb}%
  12#14567890{\expandafter\endgroup\@tempb}%
  123#1567890{\expandafter\endgroup\@tempb}%
  1234#167890{\expandafter\endgroup\@tempb}%
  12345#17890{\expandafter\endgroup\@tempb}%
  123456#1890{\expandafter\endgroup\@tempb}%
  1234567#190{\expandafter\endgroup\@tempb}%
  12345678#10{\expandafter\endgroup\@tempb}%
  123456789#1{\expandafter\endgroup\@tempb}%
  1234567890{\expandafter\endgroup\@tempc}\relax#1%
}%
%
% \GrabCatTwelveDigitsLoop{<Tokens where to append collected digits nested in curly braces>}%
%                         {<digits collected so far>}%
%                         <digits>
% 
% is an unexpandable loop for gathering explicit catcode-12-digit-characters from the
% token-stream until encountering a non-digit; initially <digits collected so far> is
% to be left empty.
\newcommand\GrabCatTwelveDigitsLoop[2]{%
  \CheckWhetherExplicitCatTwelveDigit{\GrabNextCatTwelveDigit{#1}{#2}}{#1{#2}}%
}%
\newcommand\GrabNextCatTwelveDigit[3]{%
  \GrabCatTwelveDigitsLoop{#1}{#2#3}%
}%
%
% \DefineCatTwelveDigitsCall{CsName} defines \CsName to gather explicit catcode-12-digits
% and to do \csname CsName<gathered digits>\endcsname or raise an
% error-message if \CsName<gathered digits> is undefined/\relax.
%
\newcommand\DefineCatTwelveDigitsCall[1]{%
  \CsNameToCsToken\NewDocumentCommand{#1}{}{%
    \GrabCatTwelveDigitsLoop{\CsDigitName{#1}}{}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\CsDigitName[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{#1#2}{%
    \@latex@error{Command \@backslashchar#1#2 is undefined}\@eha
  }{\csname#1#2\endcsname}%
}%

%%===============================================================================
%% End \romannumeral-driven expansion safely:
%%===============================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%===============================================================================
%% Obtain control sequence token from name of control sequence token:
%%===============================================================================
%% \CsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs}
%% ->  <stuff not in braces>\NameOfCs
%% (<stuff not in braces> may be empty.)
\@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{%
  \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
Define \h as a mechanism for gathering subsequent digits and then doing
\csname h<gathered digits>\endcsname:
\DefineCatTwelveDigitsCall{h}
\end{verbatim}
\DefineCatTwelveDigitsCall{h}


\begin{verbatim}
Define \h10:
\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{h10}{H^{(1)}_0}
\end{verbatim}

\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{h10}{H^{(1)}_0}


\begin{verbatim}
Using \h10: 
\[\CsNameToCsToken{h10}\]
\end{verbatim}

\[\CsNameToCsToken{h10}\]


\begin{verbatim}
Using \h10: 
\[\h10\]
\end{verbatim}

\[\h10\]


\begin{verbatim}
Define \h20:
\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{h20}{H^{(2)}_0}
\end{verbatim}

\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{h20}{H^{(2)}_0}


\begin{verbatim}
Using \h20: 
\[\CsNameToCsToken{h20}\]
\end{verbatim}

\[\CsNameToCsToken{h20}\]


\begin{verbatim}
Using \h20: 
\[\h20\]
\end{verbatim}

\[\h20\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Deserves an upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

What we can do in OpTeX:

```
\def\defprefix#1{%
   \def#1{\csname\csstring#1\immediateassignment\futurelet\next\numread}}
\def\numread{\isxnum\next\iftrue \ea\numreadA\else \ea\endcsname\fi}
\def\numreadA#1{#1\immediateassignment\futurelet\next\numread}
\def\isxnum#1\iftrue{\ifnum 0%
   \ifx#101\fi\ifx#111\fi\ifx#121\fi\ifx#131\fi\ifx#141\fi
   \ifx#151\fi\ifx#161\fi\ifx#171\fi\ifx#181\fi\ifx#191\fi>0
}

\defprefix\x
\sdef{x000}{three zeros}  % defines \x000 {three zeros}
\sdef{x01}{X01}           % defines \x01  {X01}
\sdef{x42}#1{result:(#1)} % defines \x42#1{result(#1)}

\x000,     % expands to three zeors 
\x01,      % expands to X01
\x42 {uff} % expands to result(uff)
\x3        % expands to \relax (like unknown \csname...\encsname)

\bye
```

Answer (score 0):

As a variable name cannot contain numbers or other symbols, the LaTex assignment is clearly incorrect: `\setlength{\myT1Col1}{0.2\columnwidth}`.

Here is how I propose to handle the problem (when I get around to it):

I will use numbers and underscore in variable names but with a switch `\myVar`. So the above statement would be written:

`\setlength{\myVar{myT1_Col1}}{0.2\columnwidth}`.

Next, I will preprocess the LaTex file (using my own code in ‘C’) replacing the numbers and underscores with some suitable alphabetical characters so that the above line becomes

`\setlength{\myTOneUSColOne}{0.2\columnwidth}`.

The problem still is that if I need to share the LaTex file, I shall have to send the preprocessed version, which does not help make things clear for others.

Wouldn’t it be great it a LaTeX Guru wrote a package to do the preprocessing?

Comment: This looks to me more like a new question than like an answer to the  question.

Comment: I felt it was related to the problem faced by the OP. I have proposed a possible solution.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: With `\CsNameToCsToken` from my answer you can do `\CsNameToCsToken\newlength{myT1Col1}` ... `\CsNameToCsToken\setlength{myT1Col1}{0.2\columnwidth}`.  With a LaTeX distribution which is up to date, you can do `\ExpandArgs{c}\newlength{myT1Col1}` ... `\ExpandArgs{c}\setlength{myT1Col1}{0.2\columnwidth}`.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem as I was implementing a simplistic method of getting the long sample name by just entering the sample number from my lab book. For example I wanted `\p{25}` to return the string `PFN/3k--C`, which is the sample name that I am mentioning in my thesis.

In the end, I did the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

% \defineSample{}{} defines other commands that can include numbers
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\defineSample}[2]{%
  \@namedef{sample@#1}{#2}%
}
% \p{} returns the long sample
\newcommand{\p}[1]{%
  \@nameuse{sample@#1}%
}
\makeatother

% Define pairs of sample numbers and long sample names
\defineSample{8}{PFN/4k--A}
\defineSample{17}{PFN/5k/DTd--A}
\defineSample{78}{ITO/2.5k--F}

\begin{document}

Sample 8: \p{8}

Sample 78: \p{78}

\end{document}
```

In my case, I only needed the `\p{}` command. But it can be adapted to different letters easily. You just have to change the first argument in `\definesamples{}{}`:

```
\defineSample{H8}{PFN/4k--A}
\defineSample{K17}{PFN/5k/DTd--A}
\defineSample{L78}{ITO/2.5k--F}

\begin{document}

Sample 8: \p{H8}

Sample 78: \p{L78}

\end{document}
```

Writing `\p{H8}` is not quite as short as writing `\H8` but it gets the job done. The solution is also very simple without the need of additional packages and the long variable names can be changed globally very easily.