# Number in name of commands?

Tags: macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Definining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/definining-commands-abbreviations-that-contain-numbers)

I wanted to know if it was possible to define a new command with a name that contains numbers?

e.g. `\newcommand{\agent1}{agent~1}`

Or even `\ag1ent` if having a number at the end is problematic.

I couldn't find the answer in the FAQ.

Comment: Duplicate of [Defining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9718/2693). The simple answer is that it's marginally possible in some cases, but not recommended.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From [`lshort`](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf), section 1.3.3:

> [Commands] start with a backslash `\` and then have a name consisting of letters only. Command names are terminated by a space, a number or any other ‘non-letter.’

Numbers are thus *not* allowed as part of a command name.

Answer (score 12):

You can always use:

```
\expandafter\def\csname agent1 \endcsname{agent 1}
```

and use it as

```
\csname agent1 \endcsname
```

Both LaTeX and ConText provide wrappers around this. LaTeX uses `\@namedef` and `\@nameuse` as wrappers, while ConTeXt uses `\setvalue` and `\getvalue` as wrappers.