# Footnote, non-inline syntax?

Tags: footnotes

I would like to use footnotes without cluttering the container paragraph. Something like:

```
This is a very long complex\footnote[a] sentence.

\foottext[a]{So complex that I would prefer to pull out the footnote text.}
```

The idea comes from the `[linktext][1], [1]: http://url.com` markdown syntax.

Comment: `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`?

Comment: Doesn't this implies manual numbering?

Comment: Related: [Can Footnotes reside in another file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/76474/5049) and [How do others manage their footnotes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/142801/5049)

Comment: @OlivierBlanvillain no, it doesn't. And it works fine with `hyperref` too.

Comment: Can you like or provide a footnotemark\footnotetext example? What is saw [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43694/31377) seems kind of manual to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`sepfootnotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sepfootnotes) package might do the trick, but the footnote content has to come before it's usage:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{sepfootnotes}
\newfootnotes{A}
\begin{document}

\Anotecontent{a}{So complex that I would prefer to pull out the footnote text.}

This is a very long complex\Anote{a} sentence.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems not possible to first state `Anote`, and _then_ provide `Anotecontent`, which is a more natural writing flow.

Answer (score 6):

The following code defines a macro `\longfootnote[fn-label]{footnote text}`, which  produces a footnote and assigns it a label which can be cross-referenced in the usual way using `\ref` to produce a footnote mark.

```
\makeatletter
  \def\longfootnote[#1]{%
    \stepcounter{footnote}%
    \@bsphack
      \protected@write\@auxout{}%
        {\string\newlabel{#1}{{%
          \string\begingroup
            \string\c@footnote \number\c@footnote\string\relax
            \string\unrestored@protected@xdef\string\@thefnmark{%
              \string\thefootnote}%
          \string\endgroup
          \string\@footnotemark
        }{\thepage}}}%
    \@esphack
    \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thefootnote}
    \@footnotetext}
\makeatother
```

This code is effectively a composition of of the code from `\label` and `\@xfootnotemark` from `latex.ltx`, writing a label to the auxiliary file which consists of a footnotemark for the new footnote. If you use an editor which recompiles whenever the labels change, you should quickly obtain a new document in which references to the long footnotes appear properly.

**Sample document.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=5mm,right=5mm,paperheight=55mm, paperwidth=62mm]{geometry}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\makeatletter
  \def\longfootnote[#1]{%
    \stepcounter{footnote}%
    \@bsphack
      \protected@write\@auxout{}%
        {\string\newlabel{#1}{{%
          \string\begingroup
            \string\c@footnote \number\c@footnote\string\relax
            \string\unrestored@protected@xdef\string\@thefnmark{%
              \string\thefootnote}%
          \string\endgroup
          \string\@footnotemark
        }{\thepage}}}%
    \@esphack
    \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thefootnote}
    \@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{A demonstration}

Here\footnote{foo} is\ref{c} a\ref{a} test\footnote{bar} paragraph.\ref{b}

\longfootnote[a]{baz}
\longfootnote[b]{gleep}
\longfootnote[c]{glorp}
\label{sec:test}

This text\footnote{fie} is a part of Section~\ref{sec:test}.
\end{document}
```

**Result.**

[image: Sample document with long footnotes and cross-references]

The long footnotes should not interfere with any other cross-referencing, as illustrated above.

Comment: i really like your solution, but it seems incompatible with `hyperref` package. If you have a fix -- please provide, thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Adding to [OlivierBlanvillain's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144943/footnote-non-inline-syntax/144948#144948), the [`sepfootnotes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sepfootnotes) package also provides the `\sepfootnotecontent` and `\sepfootnote` commands out of the box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sepfootnotes}
\begin{document}

\sepfootnotecontent{a}{So complex that I would prefer to pull out the footnote text.}
This is a very long complex\sepfootnote{a} sentence.

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: sepfootnotes]

Answer (score 4):

You might also just define a new command and use it inside the regular `\footnote` command, e.g.,

```
\newcommand{\fnOne}{A footnote.}
\newcommand{\fnTwo}{Another footnote.}

A text\footnote{\fnOne} with some\footnote{\fnTwo} footnotes.
```

Which produces the expected:

[image]

One issue with this approach is that you [cannot use numbers within command names](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28915/number-in-name-of-commands), which might or might bother you in this case.

That said, I agree that using the [setfootnotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sepfootnotes) package might be the more canonical answer and @Neil de Beaudrop 's answer is more flexible and useful in some scenarios. I'm just providing an alternative.