# tikz foreach index in variable name

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I want to have a set of variables holding numerical values (e.g., cnt1, cnt2, cnt3) and access them based on the foreach index.

For example:

```
\foreach \i in {1,...,5} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\cnt\i}{\cnt\i + 4}
}
```

Is that possible?

(edited for clarity)

Since it is not still very clear: I want to have a numerical value to a variable with a name that is constructed based on the foreach index, and I want to do numerical operations in this variable (e.g., using pgfmath* commands).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would you please be more specific on your intentions?

Comment: Regarding macro names with numbers: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/definining-commands-abbreviations-that-contain-numbers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a list structure. Here is an example of a list in tikz. Note the double braces in the list definition. In addition, the list position index starts at 0, as with most programming languages. You can find a little more on lists in the tikz documentation in the section on syntax for math expressions.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\numbers{{1,3,5,2,4}}

\foreach \i in  {0,...,4}{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{\numbers[\i] + 4}
    \draw[] (\i,0) -- (\i,\n);
}
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Not sure I understand you correctly, but you can access the index of the loop with the `count=\macro` option to the loop, *e.g.*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\noindent\foreach [count=\i] \x in {2,3,4,5,6} {%
   cnt-\i = \x \\
  }
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have no idea how to do what (I think) you're after with `pgffor`. It is fairly easy to something kind of similar with Lua, but that requires of course compiling with `lualatex`. I added an example below, where values are saved to a Lua table from a loop, and the `\getcnt` command allows you to print a value from that table based on the index.

So another of my silly little Lua-examples, which may or may not be a complete waste of your time. Compile with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\newcommand{\getcnt}[1]{%
\luaexec{
tex.sprint(cnt[#1])
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{luacode}
cnt = {}
for i=1,10 do
  cnt[i] = i^2 + 4
end
\end{luacode}
\getcnt{2} \getcnt{5}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! That was not what I had in mind exactly. I edited my question, and I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: wow! lua in latex? cool! :-)

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments if you want variable names with numbers refer to [Defining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/definining-commands-abbreviations-that-contain-numbers).

Here is a way to do what you want with variable names that have an alphabetic prefix.  You have to use `\csname cnt\i\endcsname` to access the variable.

Since the `foreach` loop is executed in a group, you have to use `\global` if you want the effect of the `\def` within the `foreach` to be available after the `\foreach`.  See the difference after the first loop and the second loop.

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\cntA}{1}
\newcommand{\cntB}{2}
\newcommand{\cntC}{3}
\newcommand{\cntD}{4}
\newcommand{\cntE}{5}


\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {A, B, ..., E} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\temp}{\csname cnt\i\endcsname + 4}
    \edef\csname cnt\i\endcsname{\temp}
}

\noindent
After 1st loop:\par
cntA = \cntA\par
cntB = \cntB\par
cntC = \cntC\par
cntD = \cntD\par
cntE = \cntE\par

\foreach \i in {A, B, ..., E} {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\temp}{\csname cnt\i\endcsname + 4}
    \expandafter\global\expandafter\edef\csname cnt\i\endcsname{\temp}
}

\medskip
\noindent
After 2nd loop:\par
cntA = \cntA\par
cntB = \cntB\par
cntC = \cntC\par
cntD = \cntD\par
cntE = \cntE\par
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you literally want to construct a macro name based on the value of the variable `\i`, you want to use the construction `\csname cnt\i\endcsname`, the result of which is exactly such a macro.  It's a little awkward to use, so use it like this:

```
\expandafter\let\expandafter\thiscnt\csname cnt\i\endcsname
% Use \thiscnt for things...
```

This is also pretty awkward, but at least you only have to write it once and (more importantly) not worry about where you need `\expandafter` when you do use it.

(If you are new to TeX programming: `\expandafter` makes the macro *after* the next one expand before processing.  You need it in the `\let` so that, when `\let` actually runs, it sees that `\thiscnt` is to be set to the *result* of `\csname...`, rather than `\csname` itself.  You need two `\expandafter`s because you're skipping two steps forward.)

This is not the best way to do a list; Frédéric's answer is much easier.