# Command/macro name cannot include numbers and symbols

Tags: macros, numbering

I would like put picture into table, and my idea is define new command as below>

- `\newcommand{\EJ471}{\includegraphics[scale=0.150]{EJ_471.jpg}}`

But compiler reports an error. If I use the command name for example `\EJa`, everything is all right. I've read similar questions as

- [Defining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9718/6621)

But still I don't understand why it does not work.

Comment: What don't you understand? In my opinion the FAQ is really clear: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=linmacnames

Comment: @Jafan It's not normal here to include 'thanks' or similar: voting is the best way to indicate that something is helpful.

Comment: NOTE: see the linked "similar question" for the *solutions* / *workarounds*. This question is for *why* it doesn't work.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A long time ago in a galaxy far, far away....

someone wrote this:

http://web.archive.org/web/20130727172127/http://www.elec.ryukoku.ac.jp/~fujii/pub/ftp/incoming/styles/kth.se/numdef.sty

Comment: Having found that via google (it was removed from ctan in 1996:-) I have put a copy here http://code.google.com/p/dpctex/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fnumdef

Comment: The link appears broken...

Comment: @barto it seems Ok from here?

Comment: The link in your comment does work, but the one in your answer gives a 'URL not found' notification.

Comment: history moves on and google kill googlecode, try https://github.com/davidcarlisle/dpctex/tree/master/numdef

Comment: This is still working great in 2022! It allowed me to name nodes in a tikz drawing a "matrix" style (with indices).

Answer (score 40):

By the rules of TeX syntax, the "name" of a macro that starts with a `\` (backslash) character must either

- consist of a *single non-alphabetical* character. Some examples: `\,` (insert thin space), `\%` ( the `%` character), `\\` (insert line break), `\[` (open display math), and `\)` (close inline math).

or

- contain *only* uppercase and lowercase alphabetical characters: `a-z` and `A-Z`. No numerals, and no other characters belonging to non-letter categories either. (Well, there *are* certain ways of assigning "letter-category" status to non-letter characters, but that's a topic for a different discussion.)

Therefore, `\EJ471` is not a valid macro name.

However, you could define a somewhat more general macro:

```
\newcommand{\EJ}[1]{\includegraphics[scale=0.150]{EJ_#1.jpg}}
```

and use it as in `\EJ{471}` to pass `EJ_471.jpg` to the `\includegraphics` command. If you needed to process further jpg files that start with `EJ_` (and end in `.jpg`, of course), you could simply keep invoking this macro with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: *Well, there are certain ways of assigning "letter-category" status to non-letter characters, but that's a topic for a different discussion.* -- I think this is the correct place ;-). The catcodes are the reasons for this.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel - I have a feeling that the OP isn't all that interested in learning about catcodes just so that he/she can make `\EJ471` into a valid TeX macro name after all. However, I may be wrong. :-) Please feel free to provide a separate, longer answer.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel As Mico says, the question here seems to be focussed on one part of the story. Catcodes are 'advanced', and moreover we've already got questions about them.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of methods given [here](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-linmacnames).

Combining some of them I've found this to be the best for a similar situation I was in.

```
\newcommand{\EJ}[1]{\csname EJ#1\endcsname}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname EJ471\endcsname{\includegraphics[scale=0.150]{EJ_471.jpg}}
\expandafter\newcommand\csname EJ8table\endcsname{\begin{tabular}{c|c} E & J \end{tabular}}

\EJ{471}
\EJ{8table}
```

This is in the same spirit as Mico's answer, but a little more versatile.