# LaTeX commands starting with a numeral

Tags: macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Definining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/definining-commands-abbreviations-that-contain-numbers)
>   [newcommand name cannot include numbers for example \Mycomand123](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66666/newcommand-name-cannot-include-numbers-for-example-mycomand123)

It seems like command names starting with a numeral are not valid when using \newcommand but are valid when using \def.  Are there any reasons not to define commands starting with a numeral?  For example:

```
\newcommand{\123MHz}{\SI{123}{MHz}\xspace}  % Causes errors
\def\123MHz{\SI{123}{MHz}}   % seems to work fine
```

Comment: they can not have a digit anywhere in the name, it is not just a restriction on starting with a digit. (It is possible to change the catcode of digit to 11 so they become letters then you can use them in names but you can not use them in lengths and other places.)

Comment: Is this only a restriction of \newcommand?  This code works fine for \def.

Comment: Don't do it. Use only letters for command names. Your `\def` doesn't define `\123MHz` but `\1` with special parameters. If you would add a definition for e.g. `\145MHz` the first definition will break.

Comment: Fair enough.  But too bad that I will need a less descriptive macro for a heavily repeated number in my manuscript.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: What about what happened a long time ago in a galaxy far far away??? Or are you trying to disown that?

Comment: @Mike: Maybe `\setcounter{myfreq}{123}` and `\newcommand{freq}{\alph{myfreq}MHz\xspace}` would serve your purpose better, if this number appears so often.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle provides a good solution here at question 66666: [newcommand name cannot include numbers for example \Mycomand123](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66666/newcommand-name-cannot-include-numbers-for-example-mycomand123) for commands with numbers (although don't think they can start with a number).

Comment: @PeterGrill as you note that isn't applicable as it requires letters at the start (to hold the actual definition)

Comment: @Mike: I would gave the numbers names that reflect their meaning. \pi is imho a much better command name than \3.14. Also in case you got the number wrong you won't have to change all the `\123` to `\132`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips everyone.  My question is more than answered.  Sorry the dup didn't come up in my searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, command names should use only letters, and as such, numbers are considered valid command delimiters.

For example:

```
\newcommand{\foo123}{blabla} % should raise an error
\newcommand{\foo}[1]{Argument is #1 ;} % typing \foo123 will be typeset as : "Argument is 1 ;23"
```

I can only assume the first definition is rejected by the compiler in order not to conflict with the second.

Comment: The first is rejected because it's syntactically incorrect. The first argument to `\newcommand` should be a backslash followed either by any number of *letters* (A-Za-z) or by a *single* nonletter.

Comment: @egreg: OP's question was about the reasons behind this syntactic restriction.

Comment: @t.verron should he perhaps be referred to the tex book? it was knuth's decision, so any rationalisation by us is probably useless.