# How to create counters with index?

Tags: counters

I need to create counters with names like mycounter1, mycounter2,... Basically this should be a counter-valued data array. The code like

```
\newcounter{index}
\newcounter{\csname mycounter\the\value{index}\endcsname}
```

does not work. It seems that it is impossible to use `\csname`...`\endcsname` for counter names. Using `\expandafter` with different variants also does not help. Is there a way to resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you give an example application? Perhaps there are more efficient ways to cope with the problem.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Counters do not have a leading backslash which is what the `\csname` would put in it. So

```
\newcounter{mycounter\Alph{index}}
```

does the job.  With counters it appears that numbers also work:

```
\newcounter{mycounter\arabic{index}}.
```

The MWE below yields:

[image]

### Notes:

- Even though you can have numerals in the counter names, it is not a good idea to have numbers in name of macros, although the second link here does provide a way to do that:

  1. [Defining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/definining-commands-abbreviations-that-contain-numbers)
  2. [Command/macro name cannot include numbers and symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66666/newcommand-name-cannot-include-numbers-e-g-mycomand123)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{index} 
\setcounter{index}{1}

\newcounter{mycounter\arabic{index}}
\newcounter{mycounter\Alph{index}}


\begin{document}
Counter\arabic{index} = \arabic{mycounter\arabic{index}}

Counter\Alph{index} = \arabic{mycounter\arabic{index}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, also numbers work, because `\newcounter{<string>}` does `\expandafter\newcount\csname c@<string>\endcsname`. So even `\newcounter{@#^&*({})}` would work. `:-)` For renewing the `\the...` command associated to it, do `\expandafter\renewcommand\csname @#^&*({})\endcsname{\alph{@#^&*({})}}`. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg those are the names that LaTeX counters should have; I don't know why Lamport et al. chose such exotic names like *page* or *chapter* for counters ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are the [`forarray`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forarray) and the [`arrayjobx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/arrayjobx) packages for handling arrays with LaTeX.

And of course LuaLaTeX offers arrays natively in Lua.