# Can new command end with a number?

Tags: macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [\newcommand name cannot include numbers, e.g., \Mycomand123](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66666/newcommand-name-cannot-include-numbers-e-g-mycomand123)

I am trying to define commands `\s1`, `\s2`, etc. Right now the the substitution is very simple but the idea would be to replace it for something that would make for sense later.

This is what I have now

```
\newcommand{\s1}{s1}
```

and I get the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.52 \newcommand{\s1}{s1}
```

If I comment the line with the newcommand definition it works fine.
(And I other other newcommands defined in the same location, and I do have a `\begin{document}`)

Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: command names  have to be all letters

Comment: LaTeX internal macros use the trick of using roman numerals for numbered macros. In your case `\si`, `\sii`, `\siii`, `\siv` etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only letters (and `@` in some cases) can be parts of names of commands defined by `\newcommand`. You have to use the lower-level macro `\@namedef`:

```
\makeatletter % to make \@namedef accessible
\@namedef{s1}{s1}
\makeatoter % to revert \makeatletter
```

However, you wouldn't be able to use such command as `\s1`, you would have to always write `\csname s1\endcsname`. I don't think it is of any use for you, just stick to letters.

*Remark: I made several simplifications in the answer. I know I did. But this is the basic idea.*