# Numbering macros

Tags: macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [\newcommand name cannot include numbers, e.g., \Mycomand123](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66666/newcommand-name-cannot-include-numbers-e-g-mycomand123)

I'm trying something that I thought would be simple

```
\def\test{Hello}
\def\test2{Hello again}
\test
\test2
```

Since I cannot control the naming I need to do some hacks.

```
\catcode30 = 11
\catcode31 = 11
\catcode32 = 11
```

which works for 0 and 1 but not for 2

I have also tried the `\catcode´1` etc with the same result.

I get a missing number treated as zero.

If anybody has any ideas on why or another solution to include numbers in the naming of defines it would be much appreciated

Comment: It would be useful to know a bit more about the use case here: it's possible to make numerals into 'letters', but will always be very awkward.

Comment: \def\testA{...} \def\testB{...} \def\testC{...}

Comment: my plan is to change em back. at the end of the def page, and also convert when needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the original question:

1. Number 0, 1, 2 are 48, 49, 50 (decimal) in ASCII, not 30, 31, 32 (hexadecimal).
2. `` \catcode`1 `` should work, but not `\catcode´1`.
3. Save number `11` for later use, or use other tricks to access origin numbers. e.g. `\def\x{\catcode...} \x`

Anyway, it's usually not a good idea to change the catcodes of numbers.

Comment: I know its no a good idea, but it is the only solution that i can find since i cannot change the name!

Comment: \catcode`1 works but not for 2 or 3 etc

Comment: the assignments for 2 3 etc don't work as having made 1 a letter it is no longer a number so can not be used to generate 11.