# Tables as commands

Tags: tables, macros

I have to do a little work but I have to use frequently the same settings for a table and I put the following code

```
\newcommand{\tab41}[4]{\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l||c|l||c|l||c|l|}
\hline
(A) & #1 & (B) & #2 (C) #3 & (D) & #4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}}
```

and it fails. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The reason is that numbers are not allowed in macro names.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Please always include the error message(s) you get. Here I get ``! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode.``, you too, right?

Comment: Is there a way to solve it? Sorry for my mistakes, I'm new here.

Comment: @DiegoSilvera Do not use digits in macro names. Use for example `\tabIVone`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because macro names may not include numbers and other non-letters (`_`, `^` and usually not `@` except where this gets changed, like inside packages and classes).

You should simply avoid having numbers in macro names. Often people use Roman numerals instead, e.g. `\mymacroiv` instead of `\mymacro4`.
There are however some ways to overcome this, see:

- [Command/macro name cannot include numbers and symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66666/2975)
- [Defining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9718/2975)

You could use the TeX (not LaTeX) way to define macros to have `41` as part of the *parameter text*, i.e the stuff the macro awaits after its name. This way you have a `\tab` macro which awaits and removes a `41` direct after its name. This works only if you don't have any other `\tab<number>` macros, however.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\tab{}% to get an error if \tab is already defined
\def\tab41#1#2#3#4{\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l||c|l||c|l||c|l|}
\hline
(A) & #1 & (B) & #2 (C) #3 & (D) & #4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}}

\tab41{a}{b}{c}{d}

\end{document}
```

--

If you really want multiple `\tab<number>` macro then you could define a `\tab` macro which reads the numbers as two arguments (not `{ }` required) and calls the correct macro which got defined using `\@namedef`, where the macro name is provided as text and therefore can include all printable characters. Because `\@namedef` is an internal LaTeX macro you need to use `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` around its usage.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\tab[2]{\@nameuse{tab#1#2}}

\@namedef{tab41}#1#2#3#4{\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l||c|l||c|l||c|l|}
\hline
(A) & #1 & (B) & #2 (C) #3 & (D) & #4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}}

\@namedef{tab25}#1#2#3#4{\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|l||c|l||c|l||c|l|}
\hline
(Other) & #1 & (table) & #2 (C) #3 & (D) & #4\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}


\tab41{a}{b}{c}{d}

\tab25{a}{b}{c}{d}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DiegoSilvera Now that you understand, avoid `\tab41`. Better safe than sorry. `;-)`