# pgfplotstableread fails to read the input file

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable, include

I am trying to typeset two different tables in a moderately large document. The data for the tables are written as comma-separated values in two different .csv files. I am including the different sections of the document into a main file using `\include{section-n}`. In each file to be included, I read the the table data with `\pgfplotstableread{table-n}{\data-n}` and then typeset it as in the `MWE`.

I am able to typeset the first table without problems, but once it tries to read the second table it fails, entering into an infinite loop. Once I break the process it spits out the following error:

> ERROR: Use of \pgfplotstableread@checkspecial@line@@ doesn't match its
>   definition.
>
> --- TeX said --- \pgfplotstable@LINE ->$S
>                           igma$,15,,,,1057 l.315 \pgfplotstableread{predevCN2.csv}{\CNPre2}
>                                                   ^^M
>
> --- HELP --- It's probably one of the picture-drawing commands, and you have used the wrong syntax for specifying an argument. If it's
>   \@array that doesn't match its definition, then there is something
>   wrong in an @-expression in the argument of an array or tabular
>   environment---perhaps a fragile command that is not \protect'ed.

Now, what is going on?

Here's my best attempt at a `MWE` which captures my intentions, yet it fails in a completely different way than my main file. I'm also not sure about why it fails, but it seems to be related.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{
  col sep=comma,
  every head row/.style={%
    before row=\toprule,%
    after row=\midrule},%
  every last row/.style={%
    after row=\bottomrule}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{firstTable.csv}
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,4,5
$\Sigma$i,ii,iii,iv,v
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{secondTable.csv}
a,b,c,d,e
1,2,3,4,5
I,II,III,IV,V
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{section1.tex}
  Here's a nice table:

  \pgfplotstableread{firstTable.csv}{\loadeddata1}

  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
       columns={A,B,C,D,E}%
       ]{\loadeddata1}
    \caption{Simple caption for a simpler table.}
    \label{tab:table1}
  \end{table}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\section{Here goes section 1}
\lipsum[1]
\include{section1}


\section{Section 2}
And here we put another table.
 \pgfplotstableread{secondTable.csv}{\loadeddata2}

 \begin{table}
   \centering
   \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
     columns={a,b,c,d,e}%
     ]{\loadeddata2}
     \caption{Fancy caption for a simple table.}
     \label{tab:table2}
 \end{table}



\end{document}


%%%% Local Variables: 
%%%% mode: latex
%%%% TeX-engine: xetex
%%%% End:
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three problems with your code:

1. You're using macro names with numbers to store the tables (`\loadeddata1`). That [doesn't work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66666/command-macro-name-cannot-include-numbers-and-symbols), you have to use letters (like `\loadeddataone`).
2. Your tables contain letters, but `\pgfplotstabletypeset` by default assumes that tables contain numbers. To typeset tables that contain text, use the `string type` key.
3. You have a macro in your first table. That needs to be protected from the parser by wrapping it in `{...}`:

Here's the corrected code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{
  col sep=comma,
  every head row/.style={%
    before row=\toprule,%
    after row=\midrule},%
  every last row/.style={%
    after row=\bottomrule}%
}

\begin{filecontents}{firstTable.csv}
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,4,5
{$\Sigma$i},ii,iii,iv,v
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{secondTable.csv}
a,b,c,d,e
1,2,3,4,5
I,II,III,IV,V
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{section1.tex}
  Here's a nice table:

  \pgfplotstableread{firstTable.csv}{\loadeddataone}

  \begin{table}
    \centering
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
       columns={A,B,C,D,E},
       string type
       ]{\loadeddataone}
    \caption{Simple caption for a simpler table.}
    \label{tab:table1}
  \end{table}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\section{Here goes section 1}
\lipsum[1]
\include{section1}


\section{Section 2}
And here we put another table.
 \pgfplotstableread{secondTable.csv}{\loadeddatatwo}

 \begin{table}
   \centering
   \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
     columns={a,b,c,d,e},
     string type
     ]{\loadeddatatwo}
     \caption{Fancy caption for a simple table.}
     \label{tab:table2}
 \end{table}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't think I would have been able to figure this out on my own!

Comment: Great answer. In a related problem, I couldn't get the LaTeX strings to be read without error, but borrowing from another of Jake's answers I successfully used the approach of replacing the string ex post ``columns/myColumnName/.append style = {string replace={1}{$<$~1 month}}``, where the ``1`` is the value I used in my csv file instead of the messy string I had to begin with.