# Use Labels to show equations

Tags: equations, labels

I want to be able to create many equations, say $a+b=c$ and $c+d=e$, save the equation as a variable but not have the equation be displayed. I simply want to have the ability to use the label/variable name(or perhaps another term?) to display them at a later point in the document. This is because the order of the equations will change later and I want to be able to easily move them around.

Essentially I want to see if I can define hidden variables that take theses equations and display these "variables" later in the document

Comment: Don't worry if you move equations. TeX will do the job for you. Just use `\begin{equation}content...\label{key}\end{equation}` and cite then with `\eqref{key}` (load `amsmath` package).

Comment: I don't want there to be a label on the side and I don't want to see the equation where I initially define it.

Comment: To remove the number just use the stared version `equation*`. But if you don't want it there so why to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
\newcommand\myeqA{$a+b=c$}
\newcommand\myeqB{$c+d=e$}
```

then when you want the first to appear, use `\myeqA`.

Comment: Perfect! This answers my question exactly

Comment: Do you know if I can name a command with a numebr in it, like myeq11 or myeq24?

Comment: No, well with a bit more work you could make the number an argument `\myeq{11}` or some such but only by defining commands that define and use internal commands you can not normally type, just using letters is a lot easier. Otherwise [this for example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/defining-commands-abbreviations-that-contain-numbers) or  [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66666/command-macro-name-cannot-include-numbers-and-symbols/66695#66695)

Answer (score 2):

Because the question doesn't specify the used format (LaTeX or something else) I give the format-independent answer:

```
\def\A{$a+b=c$}
\def\B{$c+d=e$}
```

**Warning:** The `\newcommand` is LaTeX specific feature.