# Error creating a \newcommand which uses \hspace

Tags: spacing, macros, errors, mathjax

None of my `\newcommand` declarations work for `\hspace`, with or without arguments; I use the latest MathJax with the general libraries. Attempts so far:

```
\newcommand{hs}[1]{\hspace{#1}}
\newcommand{hs}[1]{\hspace{{#1}}}
\newcommand{hs}[1]{\hspace{{#1}px}}
\newcommand{hs1}[]{\hspace{10px}}
```

I have a pageful of other `\newcommand` declarations that work just fine, unsure what's failing here. Any remedy?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The command name has to be preceded by a backslash: `\newcommand{\hs}[1]{\hspace{#1}}`. Add a backslash and it will work. The and third versions add braces that shouldn't be there, so they won't work. The fourth version won't work because numbers can't be in command names, and the first optional argument to `\newcommand` can't be empty.

Comment: Note that mathjax is not LaTeX so you should probably not expect any `\newcommand` to work.

Comment: @daleif `\newcommand` works in MathJax.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Excellent, it works - thanks. Feel free to post your response as an answer if you'd like the answer credit.

Comment: @egreg out of the box with no extra configuration?

Comment: @daleif Using the general library set, such as in the linked CDN - yes: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/latest.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML

Comment: See also [macros - Defining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/defining-commands-abbreviations-that-contain-numbers) and [numbering - Command/macro name cannot include numbers and symbols - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66666/command-macro-name-cannot-include-numbers-and-symbols) for defining commands containing numbers (not easy.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In usual conditions, all commands in TeX must be preceded by a backslash, to tell TeX that they are commands, so instead of

```
\newcommand{hs}[1]{\hspace{#1}}
```

you need

```
\newcommand{\hs}[1]{\hspace{#1}}
```

which will work as you expect.

*Side note:* If you just want to create a copy of a command with another name, you can use `\let`: `\let\hs=\hspace`. With the `\newcommand` approach the `\hs` command will *use* `\hspace`, and with the `\let` approach it will be a copy of `\hspace`. One advantage of the latter is that `\hs*{argument}` will work as you'd expect. With `\newcommand` it won't.

The second version adds an extra pair of braces that shouldn't be there, so it won't work as well.

`\hspace{{1cm}}` will expand to `\hskip{#1}\relax`, which isn't valid syntax and will throw you a `Missing number` error.

The third version is the same. The unit will only appear after the `Missing number` error, so it is of no use there. Besides, TeX doesn't know the unit `px`, so even if you remove the braces you'll still get a `Illegal unit of measure`.

The fourth contains, besides the illegal `px` unit, two problems. The first is that in usual circumstances numbers aren't allowed in command names, so you can't use `\hs1`. The second is that the first optional argument of `\newcommand` (the number of arguments) must not be empty (`[]`). An empty argument is very different from a missing argument! If you try to do that (after removing the number from the command name) you'll get another `Missing number` error because LaTeX was expecting a number there.