# How to define a macro with digits in its name using \def and a counter value?

Tags: macros, counters, expansion, csname

I need a \def whose name involves a number, with that number being value of a counter.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

% COUNTER
\newcounter{myC}
\addtocounter{myC}{1}

% DOESN'T WORK
% \def\csname\myM\value{myC}\endcsname{...}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\expandafter\def\csname\the\value{myC}\endcsname{...}` or `\@namedef{\the\value{myC}}{...}`

Comment: You may think to `\value{myC}` as the *abstract* counter's value, independent of its representation (it's not the whole truth, though). The number two is a different thing from 2 (its decimal representation).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 \def\csname\myM\value{myC}
```

would redefine `\csname` to be a macro that had to be followed by the tokens `\myM\value` and which expanded to `myC`. That isn't what you want, closer would be

```
\expandafter\def\csname...
```

but `\value{myC}` is the internal count register not the decimal expansion so you want

```
\expandafter\def\csname myM\arabic{myC}\endcsname{...}
```

Comment: @bp2017 just the same `\csname myM32\endcsname` will use the 32nd one which is fairly inconvenient which is why most people use `\roman{..}` rather than arabic then you could access it as `\myMxxxii` (see any aux file of a document using `longtable`)

Comment: possible duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66666/command-macro-name-cannot-include-numbers-and-symbols/66695#66695

Comment: @bp2017 I'm not sure that I understood that comment but I think that is the wrong way to think about it, `\csname abc\endcsname`  constructs the token `\abc`  it isn't a different kind of name that requires `csname` to access it.

Comment: @bp2017 not necessarily: if you really want digits rather than roman numbers and really want a backslash then you just need to locally `\catcode\`1=\catcode\`a` then you can use  `\myM1`

Comment: @bp2017 you can of course use backslashes to access commands inside `\csname` so long as those commands expand to character tokens not to unexpandable command tokens, hence the use of `\arabic` in the example in the answer.

Comment: @bp2017 I know, but `\arabic` is latex syntax