# Creating a command with numbers on it

Tags: macros

As I work with matrices all the time, I want to create the following command:

`\newcommand{\2x2}{2 \times 2}`

So that, for example, I can write:

Let `A \in \mathbb{K}^{\2x2}`, ... etc.

I have seen that Tex, does not allow using numbers when creating commands.

Is there a way to do this? Maybe with `\usepackage` or with a new command?

Comment: Can't just \twobytwo do the job? Or do you insist on having numbers in the command name?

Comment: I would like two have numbers in the command name, as I have also wanted to use numbers in other commands before. It will be very useful and quick to type for me.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Command/macro name cannot include numbers and symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66666/5764); [Defining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9718/5764)

Comment: `\NewDocumentCommand{\MAT}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{x}}m}{\makeMAT#1}` and `\NewDocumentCommand{\makeMAT}{mm}{\mathbb{K}^{#1\IfValueT{#2}{\times#2}}}` will allow you to use `\MAT{2x2}` and `\MAT{2}`; but also `\MAT{m x n}`

Comment: I mean, if you want `\2x2`, you might also want `\3x3` or `\3x4` and so on. Do you think this will make your input easier?

Comment: @Werner While you're at it, what do you think about merging the 2 linked questions? All the answers in both questions should be transferable to the other (in fact there's a duplicate numdef answer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `\csdef`, `\csuse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,amssymb}
\csdef{2x2}{2 \times 2}
\begin{document}
Let $A \in \mathbb{K}^{\csuse{2x2}}$, ..

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

As under normal category code régime you cannot obtain control-word-tokens like `\2x2` directly by having TeX read and tokenize .tex-input and as correct invocation of `\csname..\endcsname` in combination with `\expandafter` sometimes seems cumbersome, I offer a macro `\CsNameToCsToken` to create, e.g.,  the control-word-token `\2x2` from the character-token-sequence `2x2`.

Syntax:

`\CsNameToCsToken⟨stuff not in braces⟩{⟨NameOfCs⟩}`
→
`⟨stuff not in braces⟩\NameOfCs`

(`⟨stuff not in braces⟩` may be empty.)

(Due to `\romannumeral`-expansion the result is obtained by triggering two expansion-steps, e.g., by having two "hits" with `\expandafter`.)

With such a macro you are not bound to specific definition commands:

`\CsNameToCsToken{foo}` → `\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand{foo}` → `\newcommand\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\DeclareRobustCommand{foo}` → `\DeclareRobustCommand\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\global\long\outer\def{foo}` → `\global\long\outer\def\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\expandafter{foo}\bar` → `\expandafter\foo\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\let{foo}=\bar` → `\let\foo=\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\CsNameToCsToken\let{foo}={bar}` → `\CsNameToCsToken\let\foo={bar}` → `\let\foo=\bar`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\string{foo}` → `\string\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\meaning{foo}` → `\meaning\foo`  .

`\CsNameToCsToken\NewDocumentCommand{foo}...` → `\NewDocumentCommand\foo...`  .

```latex
\makeatletter
%%===============================================================================
%% End \romannumeral-driven expansion safely:
%%===============================================================================
\@ifdefinable\UD@stopromannumeral{\chardef\UD@stopromannumeral=`\^^00}%
%%===============================================================================
%% Obtain control sequence token from name of control sequence token:
%%===============================================================================
%% \CsNameToCsToken<stuff not in braces>{NameOfCs}
%% ->  <stuff not in braces>\NameOfCs
%% (<stuff not in braces> may be empty.)
\@ifdefinable\CsNameToCsToken{%
  \long\def\CsNameToCsToken#1#{\romannumeral\InnerCsNameToCsToken{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\InnerCsNameToCsToken[2]{%
  \expandafter\UD@exchange\expandafter{\csname#2\endcsname}{\UD@stopromannumeral#1}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\makeatother

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\CsNameToCsToken\newcommand*{2x2}{2 \times 2}

\begin{document}

Let $A \in \mathbb{K}^{\CsNameToCsToken{2x2}}$, \dots

\end{document}
```

[image]