# Hebrew text with Polyglossia and reledmac: "undefined control sequence"

Tags: polyglossia, hebrew, reledmac

I am for the first time learning to use TEX/LaTex for the purpose of using reledmac along with polyglossia to format Hebrew text critical editions. I tried to combine a basic polyglossia snippet from [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multilingual_typesetting_on_Overleaf_using_polyglossia_and_fontspec) with a basic critical note (taken from [here](https://www.academia.edu/43004455/%D7%A2%D7%9C_%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%A0%D7%AA%D7%9F_%D7%A9%D7%9C_%D7%9E%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%91%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%9F_%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%91_%D7%A8%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%99_%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A9_%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA_LaTeX) and simplified) and am getting an error. I recieve the error both on my own machine (TexMaker on windows) as well as on overleaf.

> C:\Program Files\MiKTeX\tex/latex/polyglossia\polyglossia.sty !

> Undefined control sequence. \edtextּ \edtextּ

I am using XeLaTex to compile. It seems as if polyglossia is trying to take the edtext command and failing, but that's about all I understand so if anyone could help explain this to a newbie I would greatly appreciate it.

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[series={A,B},noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar]{reledmac} 
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=hebrew]{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Hadasim CLM}

\begin{document}
\beginnumbering
\pstart
\edtextּ{עמי}{\Afootnote{ועמי}}
\pend 
\endnumbering
זוהי עובדה מבוססת שדעתו של הקורא תהיה מוסחת עלידי טקטס קריא כאשר הוא יביט בפריסתו.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is actually due to a typo. In your code, a diacritic (a vowel point) got stuck to the 2nd "t" in `\edtext`, which reads `\edtextּ`  instead.

This is not a valid *control sequence* – or *macro* or *command* – in (Xe)(La)TeX and the program complains, as you noted, `Undefined control sequence. \edtextּ` .

(In fact, there are quite a few [restrictions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66671/) as to which characters can be part of a command name in TeX – most prominently, no numbers.)

Removing the diacritic yields the functioning code

```
\edtext{עמי}{\Afootnote{ועמי}}
```