How to create a custom command (control sequence) with special characters in its name
I want to create a custom command (control sequence) whose name contains special characters (such as numbers, underscores _, or -). In order to better distinguish different commands, my code is as follows
\documentclass{article}


\expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname cmd_1_a\endcsname{m O{}}{123 #1 #2}


\begin{document}


\csname cmd_1_a\endcsname{4}[6]


\end{document}


I wrap the command name in \csname and \endcsname, which is OK in order to add special characters to the name, but I also need to use \csname,  \endcsname when I call it later. I don't want that. I want to be able to type its name \cmd_1_a directly like an ordinary command later.
Considering that _ can cause confusion in mathematical mode, it's okay not to join it. Anyway, I want the name of the custom command to contain non-alphabetic characters
In any way, please give me some hints. Thank you.

Welcome! This is really not a good idea. As you yourself point out, the underscore is used in maths mode. Moreover, it is used in the expl3 programming layer, which uses a distinct syntax to distinguish it from document-level code. There are much better ways to distinguish custom commands. The only way to do what you want is to alter the cat codes of the affect characters at the document level. That will cause you massive headaches because all of the commands you use in your document are based on the assumption that the category codes are as they expect.

@cfr Thank you for your reply. You are absolutely right. There are a lot of risks in doing so, but I still hope to add some special characters to the name without modifying the category code. But this should be done on the premise of minimizing the risk of use. I really hope to find a way to have the best of both worlds.

“without modifying the category code” is impossible.

Well, if you don't want to change the category codes and you don't want to use \csname - or, I assume, one of the equivalent wrappers - what do you want to do? You can fake something by defining a delimited command. E.g. \def\mycmd_#1_#2{...} and then you can test #1 and #2 and proceed accordingly. In simple cases, that can function as if you've defined many macros though, actually, you've only defined one. And then all that matters is that the category codes are the same when you define and use the command. But aside from that, you can't. TeX gets to _ and knows the name is over.

And, as pointed out above, use of _ would be especially unfortunate. (Though not as unfortunate as numbers.)

Can I ask how calling something \cmd_1_a helps distinguish it for a human being? You want to give your macros meaningful/descriptive names you'll find easy to remember. For example, I have an environment called infer which I use to typeset arguments in standard form (i.e. inferences). Or something like \plstyle which switches to proportional, lining figures. Either you are creating so many macros there's probably a better strategy or you're failing to imagine how little sense \cmd_1_a will make to you in 5 years time. (And I'm somebody who finds it relatively easy to remember numbers.)

@cfr numbers would be nice though, especially for internal macros - just yesterday I wrote a double loop in pstricks for which I would have liked to use loop variables \i1 and \i2 but I had to settle for \ia and \ib or something longer like \ifirst and \isecond or \ione and \itwo. Not being able to use underscores also doesn't help here, \i_a or \i_one would already be more clear.

@Marijn Personally, I think I'd find doing without numbers as numbers hard going.

"There are a lot of risks in doing so, but I still hope to add some special characters to the name without modifying the category code." that is not possible, "characters allowed in command names" and "characters of catcode 11" are two ways to say the same thing.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66666/command-macro-name-cannot-include-numbers-and-symbols/66695#66695

The way to do this is to find some character that no one else is using, and change that category code.  But all of the characters that are easily typed on a US keyboard are taken, and characters that only appear on a non-US keyboard are often typed by users of those keyboards.  So you'll need a utf-8 character that you can easily type, and that you know won't be in your source or in any style file you'll be using.

You can make numbers catcode 11  so that \i1 works, but then they are no longer valid in lengths so \hsize=100pt would be an error, and uses such as \setbox0 or \dimen0 will all fail. Most LaTeX packages will break with such a setting.
You can use
\ExpandArgs{c}\NewDocumentCommand{a name with spaces _ and 123} {m}{...#1}

and then use it as
\UseName{a name with spaces _ and 123}{arg}

But if you have such a structured name it's usually better to expose that as arguments in the interface even if internally you use a csname.
So rather than making \foo_something_1 available in the document define custom accessors:
\def\DefineFoo#1#2{\ExpandArgs{c}\NewDocumentCommand{foo_#1_#2}{m}}
\def\Foo#1#2{\UseName{foo_#1_#2}}

Then
\DefineFoo{something}{1}{...#1...}
\Foo{something}{1}{this arg}

which will access \foo_something_1 {this arg} and produce ...this arg...
