# macro names with special characters

Tags: macros

Is it possible to create macro names with special characters in it?

I would like to creates some macro's that have names like *\s1.4* and also to be able to use them like `\s1.4Test` where Test is not treated as part of the macro name(basically anything after the float is excluded as being part of the macro name)

Basically this is to avoid having to do `\s{1.4}Text` which adds two extra characters and for my purposes `\s1.4` has no issues(I will never have things like `\s1.x` and expect x not to be part of the macro so there will never be any ambiguity).

BTW, I'm defining these using a foreach:

```
\makeatletter
\foreach \m in {1.1, 2.2} 
{
    \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname s\m\endcsname{$_\mathbf{\m}$}
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Well, there is: `\expandafter\def\csname s1.4\endcsname` or the shortcut `\@namedef{s1.4}` (or `etoolbox`' `\csdef{s1.4}`). Another question is if it's wise to do that.

Comment: "no" is the most useful answer. Technically the answer to your question is "yes" you can go `\catcode'\1=11 \catcode'\.=11 \catcode'\4=11 \def\s1.4Test{...}` but you don't want to do that (as then 1 and 4 would not be numbers so you could not for example say `\hspace{14pt}`

Comment: @cgnieder it is wise for me, as I said, there will be no ambiguity. My document is not complex and never will be. When I use my code(which should be virtually identical to yours), I get an undefined macro as it is not associating the number. When I call \s1.4 it gives an error "undefined control sequence" after \s

Comment: You cannot use `\s1.4` then. This would call the macro `\s` followowed by the number `1` (assuming you haven't changed catcodes). Try `\csname s1.4\endcsname` or `\@nameuse{s1.4}` instead.

Comment: @cgnieder Well, it looks like David found a solution. Not sure how it works but it seems to work just fine.

Comment: Through a clever trick :)

Comment: Similar to [macros - Defining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/defining-commands-abbreviations-that-contain-numbers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

plain TeX example but it would work in latex, `\s` is simpler but requires a `.` `\t` is more complicated but accepts an integer.

```
\def\s#1.{%
  \def\tmp{#1.}%
  \afterassignment\xxs\count0= }

\def\xxs{\csname s\tmp\the\count0\endcsname}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\def\t{\afterassignment\xxt\count0= }

\def\xxt{\futurelet\tmp\xxxt}

\def\xxxt{%
\if.\noexpand\tmp
\expandafter\xxxxt
\else
\csname s\the\count0\expandafter\endcsname
\fi}

\def\xxxxt.{\afterassignment\xtx\count2= }

\def\xtx{\csname s\the\count0.\the\count2\endcsname}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%




\expandafter\def\csname s1.4\endcsname{one point four }
\expandafter\def\csname s2.6\endcsname{ten point six }
\expandafter\def\csname s5\endcsname{five }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\s1.4more text \s2.6 and more



\t1.4more text \t2.6 and more and \t5 yet more



\bye
```

Comment: Thanks. Adding the first two defs to my original code allows it to work.

Comment: One problem I have is sometimes I do not want a float but only an integer. The code fails. e.g., `\s2` does not work. I tried to define a non '.' for s similar to what you have done but it doesn't work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: BTW, `\count0` is not the best scratch register, because it is used for the page number ;-)

Comment: code updated with `\t`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek you have to leave the odd trap for the unwary:-) Anyone brave enough to try this should be able to rename the registers...

Answer (score 4):

In the following example macro `\s` just collects digits and dots and typesets them
as shown in the question as bold subscripts. LaTeX's `\@ifnextchar` cannot be used, because it gobbles spaces when it looks for the next token.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}[2011/04/14]

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\s}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\tmp\ltx@empty
  \s@aux
}
\newcommand*{\s@aux}{%
  \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{.}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp.}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{0}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp0}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{1}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp1}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{2}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp2}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{3}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp3}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{4}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp4}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{5}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp5}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{6}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp6}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{7}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp7}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{8}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp8}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{9}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp9}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{%
    \expandafter\s@end\expandafter{\tmp}%
  }}}}}}}}}}}%
}
\newcommand*{\s@end}[1]{%
  \endgroup
  \ensuremath{_\mathbf{#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \s1.4Test and \s2more.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Update**

It is easy to add the mapping layer including error messages, if `\s` is not followed
by digits and dots or the digit/dot string is not defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}[2011/04/14]

\makeatletter
\foreach \m in {1.1, 1.4, 2, 2.2}{%
  \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname s\m\endcsname{$_\mathbf{\m}$}%
}

\newcommand*{\s}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\tmp\ltx@empty
  \s@aux
}
\newcommand*{\s@aux}{%
  \ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{.}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp.}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{0}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp0}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{1}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp1}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{2}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp2}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{3}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp3}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{4}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp4}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{5}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp5}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{6}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp6}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{7}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp7}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{8}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp8}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{\ltx@ifnextchar@nospace{9}{%
    \edef\tmp{\tmp9}%
    \expandafter\s@aux\ltx@gobble
  }{%
    \ifx\tmp\@empty
      \@latex@error{\string\s: no digits/dots found}\@ehc
    \else
      \@ifundefined{s\tmp}{%
        \@latex@error{\string\s: Undefined `\tmp'}\@ehc
      }{%
        \@nameuse{s\tmp}%
      }%
    \fi 
    \endgroup
  }}}}}}}}}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \s1.4Test and \s2more.
\end{document}
```

In the next example, the parsed argument of `\s` is a string that starts with one or more digits, an optional dots and optional digits.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{ltxcmds}[2011/04/14]

\makeatletter
\foreach \m in {1.1, 1.4, 2, 2.2}{%
  \expandafter\protected@xdef\csname s\m\endcsname{$_\mathbf{\m}$}%
}

\newcommand*{\s}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\s@tmp\ltx@empty
  \futurelet\s@tok\s@startnum
}
\newcommand*{\s@startnum}{%
  \s@digit\s@digitordot
  \s@next
}
\newcommand*{\s@digit}[1]{%
  \def\s@next{\s@add#1}%
  \ifx0\s@tok
  \else\ifx1\s@tok
  \else\ifx2\s@tok
  \else\ifx3\s@tok
  \else\ifx4\s@tok
  \else\ifx5\s@tok
  \else\ifx6\s@tok
  \else\ifx7\s@tok
  \else\ifx8\s@tok
  \else\ifx9\s@tok
  \else
    \let\s@next\s@end
  \fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi
}
\newcommand*{\s@add}[2]{%
  \edef\s@tmp{\s@tmp#2}%
  \futurelet\s@tok
  #1%
}
\newcommand*{\s@digitordot}{%
  \let\s@next\s@end
  \ifx.\s@tok
    \def\s@next{\s@add\s@endnum}%
  \else
    \s@digit\s@digitordot
  \fi
  \s@next
}
\newcommand*{\s@endnum}{%
  \s@digit\s@endnum
  \s@next
}
\newcommand*{\s@end}{%
  \ifx\s@tmp\@empty   
    \@latex@error{\string\s: no digits/dots found}\@ehc
  \else
    \@ifundefined{s\s@tmp}{%
      \@latex@error{\string\s: Undefined `\s@tmp'}\@ehc
    }{%
      \@nameuse{s\s@tmp}%
    }%
  \fi 
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \s1.4Test and \s2more.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This definitely works for my case but seems excessively long and not very robust. In my post I can generate the commands in a loop and define there numerical part(or any part) using a simple list and with another post I can map them to output something else. e.g., `\s2` could be equivalent to `\ensuremath{_\mathbf{\map{#1}}}` where `\map` takes 2, in this case, and turns it into whatever I want. David seems to have figure out a good method that works with my original foreach and allows the mapping.

Answer (score 1):

If the second number after the period is only single digit, you can use the following:

```
\def\s#1.#2{$_\mathbf{#1.#2}$}
```

Comment: well, at this point it is 0, 1 or 2 digits.