# Passing name ending with number to \csname does not work

Tags: macros, expansion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [macro names with special characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68201/macro-names-with-special-characters)

When I use `\yyy` defined bellow it does not print `yyy`, but if I use `\xxx` it prints `xxx`. How can I make `\yyy` work?

```
\def\P1{yyy}
\def\PA{xxx}
\def\yyy{\csname P1\endcsname}
\def\xxx{\csname PA\endcsname}
```

Comment: Macro names can't have numbers in them. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68201/macro-names-with-special-characters for a workaround.

Comment: See also the [TeX FAQ entry about non-letters in macro names](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=linmacnames)

Comment: @cgnieder: very instructive that link; in fact, I did something like the final recommendation in that link before I read it. Thanks

Comment: Please notice that there's a standard way how duplicates are marked, and this should not be modified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways around this:

- Use roman numerals rather than arabic ones. For example:

  ```
  \def\Pi{yyy}
  \def\Pii{xxx}
  \def\yyy{\Pi}
  \def\xxx{\Pii}
  ```
- Use the `\csname`...`\endcsname` directive for all things non-letter. For example (note the required expansion):

  ```
  \expandafter\def\csname P1\endcsname{yyy}
  \def\PA{xxx}
  \def\yyy{\csname P1\endcsname}
  \def\xxx{\PA}
  ```
- Use `\@namedef` and `\@nameuse`. For example:

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \@namedef{P1}{yyy}
  \def\PA{xxx}
  \def\yyy{\@nameuse{P1}}
  \def\xxx{\PA}
  \makeatother
  ```

Regardless, I think one can always get away with not using numerals in control sequences.

Comment: Those are interesting workarounds, but as you say, the first option seems to be the better. Thanks