# parametrized variable with if else statements

Tags: macros, numbering

I need to create parametrized variable `\mycolor` like in [this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9719/11860).
The variable `\mycolor` defined colour based on an argument. I need to compare `#1` with values 1, 2 and so forth, but how to use if else statement in latex? Google gives result about various algorithmic packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is far from clear however

```
\newcommand\mycolor[1]{%
\ifcase#1%
red%
\or
yellow%
\else
green%
\fi}


\color{\mycolor{2}} xxx
```

makes green text. (0=red 1=yellow everything else green)