# Numbers in \newcommand not working

Tags: macros

I am trying to use the chosen solution shown [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/definining-commands-abbreviations-that-contain-numbers), for being able to use numbers in the alias I need for `\newcommand`. (That one is not able to use numbers in the alias directly strikes me as ... well, let me remain polite).

Anyway, even if I implement the top solution there, I get an error and the code cannot compile. My usage:

```
\newcommand{\H}[1]{H^{(1)}_{#1}}
And so \H1 is now equal to foo.
```

Perhaps there is something small I am missing, (I am a tex noob), and so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See here http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9720

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first problem is that `\H` is already defined. (Indeed, if you look at your compilation log, you'll see it says "LaTeX Error: Command \H already defined.") So you should change it to a different name, say, `\Hankel`. (Alternatively, you can overwrite the previous definition by using `\renewcommand` in place of `\newcommand`. But if you do, use caution, because some parts of your document might be relying on the old definition without you realising it.)

Your second problem is that superscripts (`^`) and subscripts (`_`) only work in math mode. You can toggle math mode using the `$` character. So try replacing `\Hankel1` with `$\Hankel1$`. Alternatively, you can make the macro work both inside and outside math mode, by using `\ensuremath` like so:

```
\newcommand{\Hankel}[1]{\ensuremath{H^{(1)}_{#1}}}
```

Comment: You are a genius! This works like I envisioned. Danke! ;-)