# Macro for pgfplot cycle list entry

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, pgfplots, expansion

I'm trying to define multiple cycle lists based on macro variables. The reason for this is that I need more than one list and I want to be able to change the appearance quickly while keeping the coherence.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\var1}{solid, red, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=red}, mark=o}
\newcommand{\var2}{dashed, blue, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=blue}, mark=x}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{cycle1}{
\var1\\%
\var2\\%
}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{cycle2}{
\var1\\%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[cycle list name = cycle1]
        \addplot
        coordinates
        {
            (0,0)
            (10,5)
        };
        \addplot+[only marks,forget plot]
        coordinates
        {
            (0,0)
            (10,7)
        };
    \end{axis}     
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code-example fails with the message

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfkeyscurrentkey ->\var1
```

It has probably got something to do with macro-expansion, so I tried `\noexpand` and `\expandafter` but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't use numbers in LaTeX macros- see [Defining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/defining-commands-abbreviations-that-contain-numbers) and the links within for details.

We can achieve close to your desired approach using a [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots)-based approach by using styles:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    mystyle/.style={
        solid, red, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=red}, mark=o},
    myotherstyle/.style={dashed, blue, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=blue}, mark=x}
}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{cycle1}{
    mystyle\\%
    myotherstyle\\%
}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{cycle2}{
    mystyle\\%
}
```

The idea is to set `styles` called `mystyle` and `myotherstyle`, and use them within the `cyclelist` declaration. If you wish to change these styles midway through your document, you can use, for example,

```
\pgfplotsset{mystyle/.style={blue}}
```

Here's a complete MWE to play with.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{
    mystyle/.style={
        solid, red, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=red}, mark=o},
    myotherstyle/.style={dashed, blue, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=blue}, mark=x}
}

\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{cycle1}{
    mystyle\\%
    myotherstyle\\%
}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{cycle2}{
    mystyle\\%
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[cycle list name = cycle1]
        \addplot
        coordinates
        {
            (0,0)
            (10,5)
        };
        \addplot+[only marks,forget plot]
        coordinates
        {
            (0,0)
            (10,7)
        };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Staying inside the pgfplot environment did the trick - thank you!