# Evaluating a result in \foreach

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I'm trying to animate total reflection.. so I need to evaluate the second angle inside the \foreach loop, I tried `\pgfmathparse{asin(1.33*sin(deg(\th))}`, but I got the error `!missing number, treated as zero`

```
    \documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
    \definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
    \tikzstyle arrowstyle=[scale=1]
    \tikzstyle directed=[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
        mark=at position .65 with {\arrow[arrowstyle]{stealth}}}}]
    \tikzstyle reverse directed=[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
        mark=at position .65 with {\arrowreversed[arrowstyle]{stealth};}}}]
        
        \begin{document}
        
            \foreach \th in {180,185,190,...,265}
        {\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
        % define coordinates
        \coordinate (O) at (0,0) ;
        \coordinate (A) at (0,4) ;
        \coordinate (B) at (0,-4) ;
        \def\n1{1.33}
        \def\n2{1}
        \def\r{4cm}
    
        
        % media
        \fill[blue!10!,opacity=.3] (-4,0) rectangle (4,4);
        \fill[myblue,opacity=.3] (-4,0) rectangle (4,-4);
        \node[right] at (2,2) {Fast $n_2$};
        \node[left] at (-2,-2) {Slow $n_1$};
    
        % axis
        \draw[dash pattern=on5pt off3pt] (A) -- (B) ;
    
        % rays
        \draw[red,ultra thick,directed] (\th:\r) -- (O);
        \pgfmathparse{asin(1.33*sin(deg(\th))}
        \draw[blue,directed,ultra thick,,reverse directed] (O) -- (\pgfmathresult:\r);
   
    
    \end{tikzpicture}}
    
        \end{document}
```

I'm trying to add angles to the code provided below and also to remove the grey ray when `\pgfmathresult<49`, but I'm getting the error Missing number for the first one, and for the second one, shouldn't the command line `\fi \draw[gray,directed,ultra thick] (O) -- ({-(90-\th)}:\r);` means that the line will not be drawn unless `\pgfmathresult>49`?

```
    \begin{document}

\foreach \th in {0,4,...,48,48.8,54,...,90} {%    
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,ang/.style = {draw, Straight Barb-Straight Barb, anchor=center}]
            % define coordinates

            \def\n1{1.33}
            \def\n2{1}
            \def\r{4cm}
            \coordinate (O) at (0,0) ;
            \coordinate (A) at (0,4) ;
            \coordinate (B) at (0,-4) ;
            \coordinate (C) at ({90-asin(1.33*sin(\th)) }:\r);
           \coordinate (D) at  ({270-\th}:\r);
           \coordinate (E) at  (90:\r);
           \coordinate (F) at  (270:\r);


            % media
            \fill[blue!10!,opacity=.3] (-4,0) rectangle (4,4);
            \fill[myblue,opacity=.3] (-4,0) rectangle (4,-4);
            \node[right] at (2,2) {Fast $n_2$};
            \node[left] at (-2,-2) {Slow $n_1$};

            % axis
            \draw[dash pattern=on5pt off3pt] (A) -- (B) ;

            % rays


            \draw[lava,ultra thick,directed] ({270-\th}:\r) -- (O);
            \pgfmathparse{int(\th)}
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult<49
                \draw[myblue,directed,ultra thick] (O) -- ({90-asin(1.33*sin(\th)) }:\r);
            \fi
            \draw[gray,directed,ultra thick] (O) -- ({-(90-\th)}:\r);
                \pic [draw,Straight Barb-Straight Barb, anchor=center, angle radius = 4mm, angle eccentricity=1.5, "$ \theta_i$"] {angle = F--O--D};
    \pic [draw,Straight Barb-Straight Barb, anchor=center,angle radius = 4mm, angle eccentricity=1.5,  "$ \theta$"] {angle = E--O--C};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please consider to accept the provided answer.

Comment: By the way [macros - Defining commands/abbreviations that contain numbers - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9718/defining-commands-abbreviations-that-contain-numbers)

Answer (score 6):

The error occurs because acrsine does not exist for angles greater than 90. After limiting refraction, total internal reflection occurs. Therefore, it is no longer possible to calculate the angle of the refracted ray as you try.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{lava}{rgb}{0.81, 0.06, 0.13}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.0, 0.30, 0.60}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzstyle arrowstyle=[scale=1]
\tikzstyle directed=[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
    mark=at position .65 with {\arrow[arrowstyle]{stealth}}}}]
\tikzstyle reverse directed=[postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
    mark=at position .65 with {\arrowreversed[arrowstyle]{stealth};}}}]

    
\begin{document}

\foreach \th in {0,4,...,48,48.8,54,...,90} {%    
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
            % define coordinates
            \coordinate (O) at (0,0) ;
            \coordinate (A) at (0,4) ;
            \coordinate (B) at (0,-4) ;
            \def\n1{1.33}
            \def\n2{1}
            \def\r{4cm}


            % media
            \fill[blue!10!,opacity=.3] (-4,0) rectangle (4,4);
            \fill[myblue,opacity=.3] (-4,0) rectangle (4,-4);
            \node[right] at (2,2) {Fast $n_2$};
            \node[left] at (-2,-2) {Slow $n_1$};

            % axis
            \draw[dash pattern=on5pt off3pt] (A) -- (B) ;

            % rays


            \draw[red,ultra thick,directed] ({270-\th}:\r) -- (O);
            \pgfmathparse{int(\th)}
            \ifnum\pgfmathresult<49
                \draw[blue,directed,ultra thick] (O) -- ({90-asin(1.33*sin(\th)) }:\r);
            \fi
            \draw[gray,directed,ultra thick] (O) -- ({-(90-\th)}:\r);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\end{document}
```

[image]