# The \cite command does not work when I use the multibib package

Tags: bibliographies, citing, multibib

I am trying to include multiple bibliographies in my document and I'm using the `multibib` package to do so. Everything appears to work when I write the commands with the right subscript (e.g. `\bibliographystyleX`, `\nociteX{*}`). The only command that does not work is `\citeX{}`. It gives me "citation undefined" as an error.

Here's what my code looks like

```
\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib} 
\newcites{bib1}{Bib1}
\newcites{bib2}{Bib2}
\bibliographystylebib1{achicago}
\bibliographystylebib2{achicago}
```

And then

```
\bibliographybib1{Bib1}
\nocitebib2{*}
\bibliographybib2{Bib2}
```

Comment: Command names with numbers in them are problematic in LaTeX (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9718/35864). Have you tried using `bibA` and `bibB` or some such instead of `bib1` and `bib2`?

Comment: To understand @moewe's comment: The documentation of `\newcites` in the `multibib` manual specifies: *The <suffix list> is a comma separated list of letters, i.e, the same characters which are allowed as part of a TEX command.*