# names of commands that include numbers

Tags: renewcommand

I would like to use numbers in `\newcommand` names.  Would this be possible ?

```
\newcommand{\p13}
  {\geometry{paperwidth=13cm,paperheight=21cm}}

\newcommand{\p26}
  {\geometry{paperwidth=26cm,paperheight=21cm}}
```

Comment: Specifically, yes it is possible, but [no, you probably shouldn't do that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9720/119). If you ask about what you hope to actually accomplish with this (and why), maybe someone can help you find a better approach that fits with the normal TeX syntax.

Comment: There are a number of techniques but none of the techniques is particularly good:

Comment: Welcome @Prego. Yes, you've summarised the situation explained in those answers well: there are a number of methods, none of them good. Rethink your desiderata really is the best advice anybody can give you. Note that short command names are *generally* problematic, so even if numbers were letters (in TeX parlance), this would still be disrecommended.

Comment: It all depends on the application,  There is a use for numbers and it is unfortunate they are not supported.  This is similar to the situation with Camel Case,  Although the L3 Programming Layer does accept underscores, a good design step would be to accept underscores everywhere.